# why cant i pass a url via php when using zbblock

Tags: php, http

if i try this url
http://www.rafnet.co.uk/php/raftracker.php?url=rafnet.co.uk&aff=jabbar&k=rafsystems

it works and redirects as required

BUT

when i try this, i get forbidden error from zbblock
http://www.rafnet.co.uk/php/raftracker.php?url=http://rafnet.co.uk&aff=jabbar&k=rafsystems

is it due to the "://" in the link, if so how do i allow this?

Comment: @Pekka웃: It's a PHP-based IPS. See http://www.spambotsecurity.com/zbblock.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the intrusion prevention system in question is reacting allergic on the `http` part. Little you can do except for testing out different encoding schemes to smuggle your URL past that IPS.

**Update:** Encoding `http://` as `%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F`doesn't seem to work.

Comment: right, he has to write a bypass, change his function or comment out / disable the signature at least

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a bypass or disable the signatures, which cause this.